# Kubernetes and open source cloud technologies

Tags: cloud, open-source

I need to find information about technologies (better if open source) available in the cloud: storage, database, containers, security, providers, etc..
Is there a place where I can get an overview of these technologies and know which products are available please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this repository of CNCF on [github](https://github.com/cncf/landscape) and in particular this [picture](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/cncf/landscape/master/landscape/CloudNativeLandscape_latest.png), that gives you the most updated snapshot of all available technologies.

I think it's what you need to have an overview of this wide cloud world.